# How do I calculate how large my battery's voltage needs to be to power my robot?

Tags: voltage, batteries

I'm building a robot and need to select a battery. I will be powering 3 12 V motors, a 5 V infrared sensor, an Arduino (input voltage of 5 V), and a couple of other electronic devices ranging from 3.5 to 7 V. How do I calculate how much voltage my battery needs? I'm not too familiar with how electricity works so I'm clueless.

Do I need to only get a battery with a voltage as high as my robot's highest voltage component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage is one of the two components determining the power that you need for any electrical device. The power is determined by the voltage times the current, P = U*I.

I would agree with EM Fields that you select a battery

1. by the voltage of the highes draining devices, i.e. the motors, because it is hard to transform voltages while supplying high current. You then step down all other needed voltages.
2. the amount of power you need. You calculate each components max current drain and multiply it with the applied voltage at the component (and if the voltage needed to be converted multiply another 1.1 in to take in the losses at conversion). Add all of those up and you get the maximum power drawn from your battery. Divide the number by the voltage of the battery and you get the amperage the battery needs to be able to deliver, I'll call it 'max. output'
3. now you want to find out how long your device needs to live on that battery. You multiply the max. output by the time (in hours) to get the capacity of the battery needed (in mAh or Ah).
4. buy a battery that features: the voltage from 1, the capacity from 3, and the max. output from 2.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

In a word, "Yes".

The other voltages can be generated by passive regulators or active DC - DC converters.

Comment: Why does the highest-voltage component determine the battery voltage?

Comment: It's not a general rule, but in your case it makes the most sense. There several reasons, for example your motors likely use the most current, so it's easier if you don't have to "generate" this voltage.

Comment: Because it's much easier to reduce a voltage than to increase it.

Comment: Voltage is energy per charge, right? So if I have a 12 V battery delivering 12 Volts to a motor and then to a bunch of other components after it, doesn't the voltage immediately drop to 0 after going through the motor?

Comment: @gabacabriel You need to connect your various loads in parallel with each other, so they all see 12V.  You will need to provide some kind of regulator for things which need less than 12V.

Comment: As kamuro suggested in the other answer, it might be best to determine this based on the highest-*current* component, so that you'll hopefully waste less power in regulators. I'm assuming by "component" you mean something like "module", not individual electronic components like capacitors and transistors.

Comment: Yes, @immibis, that's what I should have said. Thank you for correcting me. Also, for clarification, when a module (or even a component, for that matter) lists a voltage rating, does that rating indicate the voltage it can handle, or the voltage that it needs in order to operate?

Comment: @gabacabriel Both kinds of things *can* be called "components" (which just means "parts of something" in English) so you weren't wrong to call it that - I just wanted to be clear.

Comment: @gabacabriel Depends on the type of component/module. Be sure to read the datasheet though - it should tell you.  Almost everything will have a maximum voltage. Complex modules (motor drivers, microcontrollers, anything like that) will likely have minimum voltages as well. Some of them might be designed for only one voltage; some of them might be designed for a wide range of voltages. (E.g. I've worked on a robotics project that used a controller that would accept anything from 7 to 30 volts, because it had a built-in regulator)